# Firebird delete very slow

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Im making this simple transaction:

```
DELETE FROM ominve01 
WHERE CVE_OBS IN (SELECT CVE_OBS 
                  FROM minve01 M 
                  WHERE M.FECHA_DOCU < '31.12.2010' 
                  OR FECHA_DOCU > '31.12.2015')
```

- minve01 has 189k rows
- ominve01 has 86k rows

But it takes about 2 1/2 hours to complete deleting. Is my query bad? how can I improve it?

or how can i increase the transaction speed?

- ominve01.cve_obs is pk
- minve01.cve_obs is not pk

Comment: How long does the `SELECT` take to run on it's own? If that part takes a long time, consider an index on `minve01.FECHA_DOCU` (I would suggest a clustered index, but it seems that Firebird doesn't support them). I don't think an index on `ominve01.CVE_OBS` would help much - but you could try it anyway to see. The other thing I could think of would be to totally restructure the statement so it doesn't use `WHERE column IN (subselect)` but I don't know enough about Firebird syntax to suggest anything.

Comment: You pointed me on the right direction... i added an index to minve01.cve_obs and the deletion only took 980mS ... Thanks!!!

Comment: You might also want to consider using `EXISTS` instead of `IN`; it usually performs better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM ominve01 N 
WHERE 
exists(SELECT * FROM minve01 M 
       WHERE M.FECHA_DOCU < '31.12.2010' 
       OR FECHA_DOCU > '31.12.2015' and
N.CVE_OBS=M.CVE_OBS)
```

or execute block (you need to correct type of variable)

```
execute block
as
declare variable v integer;
begin
for SELECT M.CVE_OBS 
                  FROM minve01 M 
                  WHERE M.FECHA_DOCU < '31.12.2010' 
                  OR FECHA_DOCU > '31.12.2015'
into :v do delete from ominve01 WHERE CVE_OBS=:v;
end
```

Comment: The EXISTS solution is also very slow. Did you probe to delete with a stored procedure as rstrelba says?